# Comparing variables in two datasets using python

Tags: python

I have two datasets with over 100 variables. I want to know the variables with common names using python. How should i do it?

Comment: Writing code would be your best choice. Try it, and if you fail, we are here to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using in-built function of python library -

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']

for i in set(l1).intersection(set(l2)):
    print i,
```

or simply

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']

for i in l1:
    if i in l2:
        print i,
```

Both these codes will you output -

```
a c
```